# How to deploy key vault in different environments with same key name

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I want to deploy my key vault template in different environments through CI/CD and wanted to know if there is a way to keep only the key/secret name same in the key vault template for different environments.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which of these you mean, but key vault names must be globally unique as they have a DNS record associated with them. Keys or secrets inside them do not, and [can be populated via ARM/Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/secrets?tabs=json)